# Coudet Clarinet and Transitioning From Flute/Alto Sax

Tags: beginner, flute, saxophone, clarinet

What is a "Coudet Clarinet"? I'm a flute/Alto Sax player and was wonder if this is different from a "Clarinet" also how will the transition be?

Answer (score 2):

Coudet is simply a brand name.  Assuming you're looking at the standard Bb clarinet, the fingerings are essentially same as for the sax, with the caveat that a clarinet's "Octave" break is an octave plus a fifth rather than an octave.

As to transitioning, well every instrument has different embouchure and breath control needs.